# Default gateway changing

Tags: networking, routing

I am using 3 ethernet interfaces on Ubuntu but when I restart, the default gateway is changing to a different interface. Each time I boot I have to change default gateway back to the eth1 by deleting the default gateway and adding it back with eth1. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you configured it manually using the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, or a with software like Network Manager or wicd?

Comment: "Gateway" is not equal to "route". A gateway is specific to an interface where an route says which interface should be used.

Comment: The gateway is usually an interface on a remote device which the local node is relying on for routing decisions. A route statement itself can refer to a local interface or not, but the routing destination has to be discoverable from a recursive lookup, connected interface, or default route.  A default route or default gateway is the 'gateway of last resort' -- which will be used in the absence of a more specific route being available.

Comment: Can you provide your routing table and list of interface, and other any relevant network configuration you've done?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To temporarily change the default route you can use an [ip command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/ip.8.html) like this:

```
$ sudo ip route change default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

If you have a static ip configuration in [`/etc/network/interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/interfaces.5.html) you can add a gateway statement to make this permanent.

```
iface eth0 inet static
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    […]
```

Using DHCP to configure networking you have to adjust another file instead. Add the supersede statement in [`/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dhclient.conf.5.html).

```
supersede routers 192.168.1.1;
```

Comment: Scriptable version (should be a space between the quotation marks):
`echo supersede routers $(ip route | grep default | cut -f3 -d" ")\; | sudo tee --append /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Comment: What if I have multiple interfaces? Shouldn't they all have a 'gateway' for each interface? But what affects the example ''default via 192.168.3.1 dev eth6" output of ip route command? It lists a specific interface, right?

Answer (score 8):

Open the file `/etc/network/interfaces`

find desired interface and add following:

```
gateway 192.x.x.x
```

Restart network:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: What if the desired interface is configured via DHCP and I don't know the gateway address it will assign?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for my wifi interface `wlp3s0` on Ubuntu 18.04. It was affecting my ability to connect to Android tethering and router outside home. The way to solve the issue for me was to comment in file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` the following:

```
interface wlp3s0
        static ip_address=192.168.0.16/24
        static routers=192.168.0.1
        static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

to get the following

```
#interface wlp3s0
#        static ip_address=192.168.0.16/24
#        static routers=192.168.0.1
#        static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

Then, I've disconnected from my current network and reconnected an tried `route -n` or `nmcli` to see changes

You can also remove the same lines when you are sure it works for you.

Because of these lines, the NetworkManager was always adding a default route with a wrong gateway, in particular when I was not on my home network.
I was getting "Destination Host Unreachable" when I was doing a `ping 8.8.8.8`. Hardcoding a gateway in `/etc/network/interfaces` was not a viable solution as I connect a lot to public wifis (so, never the same wifi router or gateway) and normally DHCP should work "out of the box" IMHO.

PS: I've never edited manually `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` so I don't know why the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` did contain these lines.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem.